# Как загружать и использовать классы через Composer глобально в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, классы, composer, autoload

В своем проекте `Laravel` на сервере установил `Composer` глобально и локально в папку с сайтом (то есть два раза).
Соответственно перенесенные после создания сайта с локального ПК классы работают и они расположены в локальной папке `vendor`, а вот в процессе доработки сайта, подключаемые новые классы, я так понял, устанавливаются глобально в папку `vendor` на уровень выше папки с сайтом на сервере и при этом не работают.
Вопрос - как правильно сделать, чтобы все подключаемые классы и `composer` были глобальными?
 Как перенести старые уже подключенные классы из локального composer в глобальный? Ну не тупо же копировать файлы с папками...
Может кто-то посоветует нормальные статьи или видеоуроки, где бы понятным новичку языком с примерами показано, зачем тут файлы `composer.json`, `composer.lock` и `composer.phar`, а так же `autoload`, `psr-4`, `psr-0` и тому подобное.
 В сети много информации, но трудно понять.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: У Вас есть классы которые используются в одном и том же проекте и вы хотите не копировать их постоянно в новый проект, а хранить в одном месте и подключать во все нужные проекты?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, всё верно, но по факту проект подхватывает те классы которые в папке vendor которая в папке с сайтом, а те классы которые в папке vendor общей для всех сайтов (на уровень выше папки www) не подхватывает

Answer (score 1):

Твоя папка vendor полностью зависит от содержимого файла composer.json в корне твоего проекта. Просто скопируй туда построчно зависимости, которые тебе нужны и выполни composer update.

Upd: composer.phar должен лежать в домашней папке. Оттуда надо удалить все остальные файлы composer и папку vendor. Далее надо добавить в .bashrc строку `alias composer="php $HOME/composer.phar -vv"`. После этого выполняешь `. .bashrc`, идешь в папку проекта, проверяешь команду composer и спокойно пользуешься.

То есть в домашней папке только исполняемый файл композера. В папке проекта он не нужен, там нужен composer.json.

Да еще: это не называется глобальной установкой, это установка для твоего юзера. Пакеты же не устанавливаются глобально или для юзера никогда! Они должны быть в папке vendor в твоем проекте.

PS: не рановато ли ты взялся за ларку? Изучил бы сначала баш и устройство фс на линуксе.

Comment: так получилось что папки vendor у меня две, одна в корне сайта (в папке с сайтом) на сервере, а вторая просто в корне сервера (на два уровня выше папки с сайтом). Когда в консоле на сервере устанавливаю какой-нибудь пакет (например $ php composer.phar require jenssegers/agent) то файлы этого пакета появляются в папке vendor которая в корне сервера (на два уровня выше папки с сайтом и там же кстати и файлы composer.json), так вот в файле composer.json что в корне сервера появляются эти зависимости, но на сайте когда пробую использовать пишет что класс не найден

Comment: Когда в консоле на сервере пробую установить прямо в каталог с сайтом командой $ php ~/www/mysite.com/composer.phar require jenssegers/agent, то пишет мол установлено и в файле composer.json в корне сайта не появляется строчки с зависимостью и в папке vendor в корне сайта не появляется папки с установленным пакетом. Собственно что делать? Как устанавливать дополнительные классы?

Comment: Файла .bashrc так и не нашел, ни в какой папке его нет. Есть .bash_profile, но это видимо не то. Ларку изучать начал не рано, уже пора было "ещё вчера". Вобщем пошёл изучать это всё, видимо просто так без потерь с windows не перенести сайт на хостинг, это целая наука.

Comment: Напиши мне в телеграм

Answer (score 0):

> установил Composer глобально и локально в папку с сайтом

Зачем? Достаточно одной глобальной установки

> я так понял, устанавливаются глобально в папку vendor на уровень выше

Не верно вы поняли. Композер устанавливает пакеты в ту папку, в которой вы находитесь на текущий момент. Пример. предположим, что ваш сайт находится на сервере по следующему пути

```
home/user/web/site.com
```

В таком случае для установки пакета из репозитория в директорию с сайтом необходимо в консоли выполнить следующие команды:

```
cd /home/user/web/site.com    
composer require cocur/slugify
```

Comment: cd /home/user/web/site.com    
    composer require cocur/slugify

так не работает, вернее если правильно понял у меня должно быть

    $ cd ~/www/mysite.com/ 
    $ composer require jenssegers/agent

пишет Command Not Found

Comment: Если "Композер устанавливает пакеты в ту папку, в которой вы находитесь на текущий момент", то в чем разница между глобальной установкой компосера и обычной?

Comment: Если у вас десятки сайтов на сервере, смысл устанавливать композер локально на каждый, если можно один раз установить глобально и юзать его?

Comment: composer require cocur/slugify так не работает... Попробуйте так: php composer.phar require cocur/slugify Если нет, то подскажите, в какую папку установлен глобальный композер? И покажите что содержится в path. запустив в консоли команду: $PATH

Comment: Собственно я и хочу чтобы был один глобальный компосер, но по факту их два и как-то надо их объединить. Глобальный компосер (если я правильно понял) на уровень выше папки www (на этом же уровне папка vendor которая относится к глобальному компосеру), а локальный внутри папки с сайтом и там своя папка vendor. На сайте реально работают классы из локального компосера, а когда устанавливаю классы в глобальный, то в работе скрипта на сайте пишет "class not found"
Команда $PATH мне выдала "/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin: No such file or dir ectory"